# Wordpress best Profile plugin or setup

Tags: wordpress, plugins, profile

I have a website .. http://Jwlry.Co and need a profile page for each jeweller on the website. Can anyone suggest a good profile page plugin or the best way to set this up?

Comment: Please edit the question and describe specifically what features you're after, as well as the current setup.

Answer (score 0):

They can use the profile page on your-site.com/wp-admin/profile.php Install a plugin like Simple Local Avatar for profile images and you are set to go.